# Using jQuery, can't add behavior on click to buttons created with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some buttons and I added some behavior on click to all of them with jQuery and they worked fine, but now that those buttons are generated dynamically by changing the `innerHTM`L of the div with a script, the behavior don't work anymore

Here is an example, like this every time I click any of the two buttons, it show an alert with the message `'clicked'`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0Lew3r5/5/)

```js
$('.foo').on('click', function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home">
    <button class='foo' > Test </button>
    <button class='foo' > Test </button>
</div>
```

But if I insert the buttons by changing the `innerHTML` of home with the button generate, it does not works anymore

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0Lew3r5/6/)

```js
$(".gen").on("click", function(){
   $('.home').html(
     "<button class='foo' > Test </button>" +
     "<button class='foo' > Test </button>");
})


$('.foo').on('click', function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button class="gen" > Generate  </button>
</div>

<div class="home">

</div>
```

I really don't know what's going on

Comment: `$('.foo')` selects certain elements.  `.on()` adds an event handler to only the selected elements.  Any new elements with the "foo" class will not have that handler.  Either add them manually to the new elements or better still use a delegate `$(document).on('click', '.foo', ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.foo')` selects certain elements. `.on()` adds an event handler to only the selected elements.  Any new elements with the "foo" class will not have that handler. Either add them manually to the new elements or better still use a delegate.

Basically, since your "foo" elements do not exist until after you click "generate", the call to `.on()` adds a handler to nothing.

Here's a solution using jQuery's delegate implementation

```js
 $(".gen").on("click", function(){
   $('.home').html(
     "<button class='foo' > Test </button>" +
     "<button class='foo' > Test </button>");
})


$(document).on('click', '.foo', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button class="gen" > Generate  </button>
</div>

<div class="home">

</div>
```